# How do you say "he will be on TV"?

Tags: expression

I can't figure out how to say “I will be on TV” or “he will be on TV" correctly (in reference to being on a TV show that will be aired). The best I can think of something like »Ich werde am Fernseher sein« and I think that using »auf dem« or »im« instead of »am« might mean literally “on top of the TV” and “inside the TV set” respectively.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Colloquial:

> Ich bin im Fernsehen. (I am on TV.)
>   Ich werde im Fernsehen sein. (I will be on TV.)
>   Er/Sie/Es ist im Fernsehen. (He/She/It is on TV.)
>   Er/Sie/Es wird im Fernsehen sein. (He/She/It will be on TV.)

Better style:

> Ich bin im Fernsehen zu sehen.
>   Ich werde im Fernsehen zu sehen sein.
>   Er/Sie/Es ist im Fernsehen zu sehen.
>   Er/Sie/Es wird im Fernsehen zu sehen sein.

Don't mix up:

**Der Fernseher**
The technical device that receives the program and displays the picture and emits the sound.

**Das Fernsehen**
The program, the show. All that has to exist to produce something that the *Fernseher* can receive. It's like »das Theater« (*the theatre*), that is not just the building, but also the institution, the crew, the special life-style, and all those things.

So, when you are *im Fernseher*, then you are a very tiny person, small enough to fit into the technical device.

But if you are *im Fernsehen*, then you are part of the show that is broadcasted.

Comment: A long time ago, you needed to be tiny. Then you just needed to be child-sized. Now you need to be a stingray or equally flat ;)

Comment: English has that sense for television too. Like, "What do you do?" "Oh, I'm in television."

Comment: @mattdm I think it's "I'm on tv" not "in", right?

Comment: @christoph If you are an actor, probably. But if you are a writer, director, producer, or other part of the industry, "in". (And an actor could say it that way too.)

Comment: @Takkat: Ja, so gehts auch: Alles löschen, was nach Kritik an deiner »Moderation« aussieht. Ein feiner Moderator bist du!

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: as said - please use [meta] or [chat] to discuss this.  Post comments should not be used for this. This is a Network wide policy, there is nothing new to this.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add something to Hubert's answer, since I can't comment (not enough reputation) I'll just answer here.

> "Ich werde im Fernsehen sein zu sehen sein."

and

> "Er/Sie/Es wird im Fernsehen sein zu sehen sein."

is wrong because of the double usage of "sein"

Just using:

> "Ich werde im Fernsehen zu sehen sein."

and

> "Er/Sie/Es wird im Fernsehen zu sehen sein."

Is correct.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out these mistakes. I fixed them in Hubert's answer. (I believe you could have made an edit suggestion yourself, even with 1 reputation; that would have been the preferred path.) You should now delete your answer.

Comment: Sorry, it was just a typo. It was late in the evening when I wrote it, and my wife wanted me to go to bed. So I was tiered and in a hurry. Best conditions to make mistakes. Thanks chirlu for your correction!

Comment: @Takkat: Nachdem dieses Posting keine Antwort auf die gestellte Frage ist, und dank chirlus Korrektur auch der Grund für dieses Posting verschwunden ist, kannst du nicht einfach diese »Antwort« löschen?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast They received +3 upvotes which would be removed by deleting that answer. But the OP (or oyu) may want to [edit] their answer to remove the references to that now non-existing typo.

Comment: @Takat: Das Editieren der »Antwort«, um sie an die vorliegenden Gegebenheiten anzupassen, würde auf ein Löschen der Antwort hinauslaufen. Der Verfasser der Antwort hat selbst (in dem von dir gelöschten Teil) geschrieben, dass er eigentlich einen Kommentar hinterlassen wollte, und die Antwort also gar nicht als solche beabsichtigt war. Dass dann Andere den Fehler gemacht haben, diese Nicht-Antwort auch noch hochzuwerten, ist keine Leistung, die dem Antwortenden positiv angerechnet werden müsste.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Why not just let's wait for the OP to return? Moderation  in a rush is not a good idea in such cases.

Comment: @Takkat: But deleting the sentence where the OP explained why he wrote this answer, and deleting the comments where others explained how it came to this situation is a good idea?

Comment: If the community wants this answer deleted go ahead and **vote** to "delete" but this is not a case to call a moderator. This answer is neither harmful, offensive, spam, or "not an answer". **It is not what flags are for.** Please understand that a moderator is here to also protect others. Deleting upvoted posts from a user who was helpful in the first place but now simply did not have the time to come back it not really good style. Deleting an **obsolete matter** is someting different. Is is what we always do here.

Comment: @Takkat, while I agree with most what you're writing, this was indeed not an answer, it even said so in the first line.

Comment: @Takkat: We can't cast delete votes until after three days or so. (Edit: Only for questions with a negative score, actually.)

Comment: Why do my comments disappear? I did NOT delete them! I wrote: (Begin of quote, not verbatim, from memory) @Takkat: But deleting the sentence, where the OP explained, that his »answer« was not meant as an answer but as an comment, is a good idea? And deleting my comment where I explained, that I made an typo that chirlu already corrected, is a good idea? Do you think it is a good idea to delete my comment, where I wrote that it is not wamp's effort that others upvoted his NON-answer? (End of quote) And now you are going to delete my other comments? You think this is what a moderator should do?

Comment: Ich finde das klasse hier. Ein Neuer kommt mit einem hilfreichen Kommentar, und alle zeigen, was das hier für ein Kindergarten ist.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Das Problem ist, dass er es eben NICHT als Kommentar, sondern als Antwort gepostet hat, und dass die ganze »Antwort« in dem Moment aufgehört hat hilfreich zu sein, als chirlu meinen Fehler ausgebessert hat. Das viel größere Problem ist aber, dass der Moderator anstelle die überflüssig gewordene und nicht mehr hilfreiche Antwort zu löschen, viel lieber Kommentare löscht, in denen sein Verhalten kritisiert wird.

Comment: **Please do not abuse post comments for meta discussions. In case there were issue with the post please discuss this on [the related meta post](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/934/should-we-try-to-repair-non-answers-that-were-intended-as-comments). Thank you.**

Comment: @Takkat, danke für das Wiederherstellen des ursprünglichen Zustandes. Du hast nur vergessen, auch ein Rollback beim Beitrag selbst zu machen. Ich habe das nun für dich erledigt.